# Enableing c++ project system logging in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/21/enable-c-project-system-logging.aspx) article i need to find enable visual studio logging to trace down an error. I found no other way for c++ to do this so i had to use the technique described in the article, but there is a problem:

The article mentions a files `\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config` that is required to be edited. However in **Visual studio 2013 Express for windows desktop** there is no such file. (1) Where can i find this file for vs2013 exp ? Or is there any other way to enable debug logging for c++ ?

(2) Is it possible for this file to be loaded from somewhere else since i have other versions (not express) of visual studio installed?

Answer (score 0):

if you have it in any other location, copy and edit that. If not, try creating a new file with the right name and put the snippet in there.

EDIT:

The other way to enable logging is to run MSBuild in a command line and [enable logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx) using it.

`MSBuild Myproject.vcxproj /fl /flp:logfile=mylog.log;verbosity=diagnostic`

Comment: doesn't seem to work, i changed all `devenv.exe.config` i could find and even moved the config from 2012 to the 2013 installation folder.

Comment: does not work , visual studio express installation doesn't seem to have MSBuild. I found the file i was looking for later , it's name was `WDExpress.exe.config` but the configuration described in the article doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the help.